# Display paragraph in Jade template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have started working on a sample NodeJS / Express  web application , 
and I am using Jade template engine.

Below is the partial .jade code for one of the screens.

```
html
  head
   script(src='/js/bootstrap.min.js')
   script(src='/angular/angular.min.js')
   link(href='/css/bootstrap.css' , rel='stylesheet')
 body
  div(class='container') 
      p= error
```

My intention is to have "p" element within the div

```
<div class='container'>
<p>Error message comes here.. </p>
</div>
```

But what is happing is "p" element is after div

```
<div class='container'>
</div>
<p>Error message comes here.. </p>
```

Please let me know what needs to be modified so that "p" is within div.

Comment: your indentation is all weird, please make sure everything is spaced with two spaces in the `jade` file. Outside of that, your code looks fine. You could use just `.container` instead of `div(class="container")`. I just tried your code on `jade-lang.com` and it's fine there.

Comment: @Sgnl , As you said , if I paste the code in jade-lang.com , it is working fine . But in my-case when it gets rendered from server , its not working.

Comment: I just tried your code on my server and it works just fine. So it could be the error causing the problem so what is the error?

Comment: @Sgnl , @ Molda I am new to Jade , so my question made sound stupid , I have realized that indentation of jade code decides where the tags end. Am I correct.

Comment: @CleanCrispCode yes, indentation in jade is important and decides where tags end.

Answer (score 0):

Your code may be indented in the wrong way. Try this:

```
html
  head
   script(src='/js/bootstrap.min.js')
   script(src='/angular/angular.min.js')
   link(href='/css/bootstrap.css',rel='stylesheet')
 body
  .container 
    p=error
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied the jade code and seems you indented unevenly. Try this :

```
html
    head
        script(src='/js/bootstrap.min.js')
        script(src='/angular/angular.min.js')
        link(href='/css/bootstrap.css' , rel='stylesheet')
    body
        .container
            p error
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

> div.container
>
> > p= error